# Is there a Shi'a based report that Prophet (as) wiped on bare feet?

Tags: shiism, wudu, taharah

Depending on how you read the verse of wudhu (5:6 in the Qur'an) you can wash the feet or wipe on them. Sunnis wash the feet as in the 1st reading and wipe on socks in a state of wudhu as in the 2nd reading via the Sunni ahadith.  I would like to see reports from the Shi'a where the Prophet (as) actually wiped on his bare feet please. Shi'a don't accept washing the feet at all I understand.

Comment: Did you ask for Shia sources only? I had also [cited several narrations from Sunni sources](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/47058/revisions) in my answer but they were removed.

Answer (score 3):

Shias use hadiths from Imam Baqir (علیه السلام) and Imam Sadiq (علیه اسلام) to support their position.

To quote a Shia source:

> (باب) * (صفة الوضوء) * 1 - علي بن إبراهيم، عن محمد بن عيسى، عن يونس بن عبد الرحمن، عن أبان وجميل، عن زرارة قال: حكى لنا أبو جعفر (عليه السلام) وضوء رسول الله (صلى الله عليه وآله) فدعا بقدح فأخذ كفا من ماء فأسدله على وجهه ثم مسح وجهه من الجانبين جميعا ثم أعاد يده اليسرى في الاناء فأسدلها على يده اليمنى ثم مسح جوانبها ثم أعاد اليمنى في الاناء فصبها على اليسرى ثم صنع بها كما صنع باليمنى ثم مسح بما بقي في يده رأسه ورجليه ولم يعدهما في الاناء.
>
> Zurara said: Abu Ja'far (Imam Baqir, علیه السلام) recounted to us the ablution of Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). So he asked for a bowl and took a palm of water and poured it on his face and then wiped all the two sides of his face. Then he returned his left hand into the bowl and poured it over his right arm and wiped over its sides. Then he returned his right hand into the bowl and poured it on his left arm and did to it what he did to his right arm. Then he wiped by what was left in hand over his head and feet and didn't return them into the bowl. ([al-Kafi](http://lib.eshia.ir/11005/3/24))

As you see there's no mention of washing the feet but wiping them by the water left on the hand. There are several more hadiths like this from al-Kafi.

Comment: Salaam , may I have your email ? I've a question about Shia islam please.

Answer (score 0):

This is debatable question. It all depends upon how you translate the word `famsahu` means masah. Washing or just wiping(touching). 
The verse in Quran is

> (O you who believe! when you rise up to prayer, wash your faces and your hands as far as the elbows and wipe your heads and your feet to the (two) ankles. 5:6)

If you take the meaning of famsahu as washing, it simply implies that you should wash your head as well as wash your feet. **Read it again, wash your head too if the word means washing.** 
But if you take the meaning of `famsahu` as wipe that means you just have to wipe your head and wipe your feet[just touching]. 
What sunni brethern do is wipe the head but wash the feet and in quran, there is only one word used `famsahu`. It either means wiping or washing. If it means washing, then you have to **WASH** both head as well as feet.
[image: here is the only one word used]

Regarding the comment below:
Yes, sunni brethern as well as shia brethern wash their faces. But for washing the word used is different.
Here it is 
[image: washing]
If God have asked to wash the feet but wipe the head then the `fagsilu` word would have been used for washing feet as this has been used for washing the face and hands.

Comment: The translation/pictures you are using definitely don't help your case. Do you see how Wojooha and Aediya end in a fat-ha. And Arjula also ends in a fat-ha. If it was with Amsaho Biro-oos**i**kum (Roo-si ends in a kasrah) it would have ended in a kasrah as per Arabic grammar. So, gramatically, from your pictures it can be deduced that Arjulakum (your feet) comes under Faghsiloo (wash).

Comment: I would suggest you use Shia ahadith to support the practice instead.

Comment: @TheZ It's a confusing verse indeed, and it can be interpreted both ways. You have the different i'rab (إعراب) to support your case, and the Shia point to different verbs used to support theirs. So the verse itself doesn't unequivocally support either position.

Answer (score 0):

There are several hadith in Wasail Al Shia from the Prophet (as) on the method of Wudhu. Refer to the following link to see all the hadith in the chapter on Wudhu:

https://wasail-al-shia.net/c/158

Here is one of them:

قال أبو جعفر عليه السلام: ألا أحكي لكم وضوء رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله؟ فقلنا: بلى، فدعا بقعب فيه شئ من ماء فوضعه بين يديه،

Abu Ja'far (peace be upon him) said: "Shall I narrate to you the ablution of the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him)?" So we said: "Yes." Then he called for a small vessel/bowl with some water in it and placed it before him.

ثم حسر عن ذراعيه ثم غمس فيه كفه اليمنى، ثم قال: هكذا إذا كانت الكف طاهرة، ثم غرف ملأها ماء، فوضعها على جبهته، ثم قال: بسم الله، وسدله على أطراف لحيته، ثم أمر يده على وجهه وظاهر جبهته مرة واحدة.

Then he uncovered his arms and dipped his right hand in it, then he said: This is how it is done if the hand is clean, then scooped with it a full hand of water, placed it on his forehead, then said: "In the name of Allah," and let it flow down to the tips of his beard. Then he passed his hand over his face and the exterior of his forehead once.

ثم غمس يده اليسرى، فغرف بها ملأها ثم وضعه على مرفقه اليمنى فأمر كفه على ساعده حتى جرى الماء على أطراف أصابعه، ثم غرف بيمينه ملأها فوضعه على مرفقه اليسرى فأمر كفه على ساعده حتى جرى الماء على أطراف أصابعه،

Then he dipped his left hand, scooped with it a full hand of water, placed it on his right elbow, and ran his palm over his forearm until the water reached his fingertips. Then he scooped with his right hand a full hand of water, placed it on his left elbow, and did the same until the water reached his fingertips.

ومسح مقدم رأسه، وظهر قدميه، ببلة يساره، وبقية بلة يمناه.

He wiped the front part of his head and the back of his feet with the moisture of his left hand and the remaining moisture of his right hand.

وقال أبو جعفر عليه السلام: إن الله وتر، يحب الوتر، فقد يجزيك من الوضوء ثلاث غرفات: واحدة للوجه، واثنتان للذراعين، وتمسح ببلة يمناك ناصيتك، وما بقي من بلة يمينك ظهر قدمك اليمنى، وتمسح ببلة يسارك ظهر قدمك اليسرى.

Abu Ja'far (peace be upon him) said: "Verily, Allah is singular (odd) and loves odd numbers, so three scoops of water may suffice you for ablution: one for the face, two for the arms, and with the moisture of your right hand, wipe your forehead and with what remains from the moisture of your right hand, the back of your right foot, and with the moisture of your left hand, the back of your left foot."

قال زرارة: قال أبو جعفر عليه السلام: سأل رجل أمير المؤمنين عليه السلام عن وضوء رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله، فحكى له مثل ذلك.

Zurarah said: "A man asked the Commander of the Believers (peace be upon him) about the ablution of the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him), and he described to him similar to that."

ورواه الصدوق مرسلا إلا أنه قال: ومسح على مقدم رأسه وظهر قدميه ببلة بقية مائه، ولم يزد على ذلك.

And it was narrated by Al-Saduq similarly except that he mentioned wiping on the front part of the head and the back of the feet with the remaining moisture of the water, and he did not add beyond that.

Wasail Al Shia Vol. 1, Section 7, Chapter 15, Hadith 1021
https://wasail-al-shia.net/h/1021

Answer (score -1):

The natation mentioned is not even authentic.
You should type" how the prophet was performing ablution" in Google, and the will give authentic a'hadith about the real way to perform ablution.